# submit multipart/form-data POST with c# and webrequest

Tags: c#, forms, multipartform-data, webrequest

Hey I am trying to submit a multipart/form-data request.

```
        string sURL = base_url + "?action=add-torrent";
        WebRequest torrent_post = WebRequest.Create(sURL);
        torrent_post.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
        torrent_post.Method = "POST";
        var reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("one.torrent");
        Debug.WriteLine(bytes[5]);
        using (Stream requestStream = torrent_post.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }
```

the api I am trying to send the data is:

```
http://[iP]:[PORT]/gui/?action=add-file

This action is different from the other actions in that it uses HTTP POST instead of HTTP GET to submit data to µTorrent. The HTTP form must use an enctype of "multipart/form-data" and have an input field of type "file" with name "torrent_file" that stores the local path to the file to upload to µTorrent.
```

based on this the only thing I am missing is the actual input fields. how would one implement it? thanks

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: how would I implement the actual input fields into the request?

Comment: Use `HttpClient` + `MultipartFormDataContent` instead of WebRequest

Comment: not possible for my application